# c# collection was modified enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: c#

I am creating a project program and trying to detect textbox changes befor closing form, I am getting the following error:

> C# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Below is the code I am referring to:

```
public partial class PatientFiles : Form, ILookup
{
    bool NeedSaving = false;
```

I think my error here but how can fix this

```
void CheckChanges(Control.ControlCollection cc)
{
    try{
            foreach (Control ctrl in cc)
            {
                MaskedTextBox mtxtBox = ctrl as MaskedTextBox;
                if (mtxtBox != null)
                {
                    mtxtBox.TextChanged +=TextWasChanged;
                }
                else
                {
                    TextBox txtBox = ctrl as TextBox;
                    if (txtBox != null)
                    {
                        txtBox.TextChanged += TextWasChanged;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ComboBox cmb = ctrl as ComboBox;
                        if (cmb != null)
                        {
                            cmb.SelectedIndexChanged +=TextWasChanged;
                        }
                    }
                }
                CheckChanges(ctrl.Controls);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

> //formload

```
  private void frmPatient_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   EnableNavigation();
   //txtEngName.TextChanged += new EventHandler(TextWasChanged);
   CheckChanges(this.Controls);

   }` 

   public void TextWasChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   NeedSaving = true;
  }`

 private void PatientFiles_FormClosing(object sender,    FormClosingEventArgs e)
  {
   //NeedSaving();
   // Disable Navigation On Form closing
   if (NeedSaving)
   {

       DialogResult dt = MessageBox.Show("Save Changes", "information", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
       if (dt == DialogResult.Yes)
       {
           SaveData();
           //DisableNavigation();
       }

       else if (dt == DialogResult.No)
       {

           DisableNavigation();
           NeedSaving = false;
           this.Close();
       }
       else if (dt == DialogResult.Cancel)
           e.Cancel = true;
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's there? You do know where the exception is being thrown, right?

Comment: Can you step through and see where error is occurring? As said by @Richard Schneider in answer, you should not get this error as collection is not modified inside for loop.

Answer (score 1):

This error can appear when same collection is used in two threads: in one you modify the collection (add, remove, clear, ...) and in the other you iterate over the collection. So, do you use threads across your application? The snippet you put doesn't indicate this, it only shows that `frmPatient_Load` is (supposedly) run in the UI thread. If the answer is yes then you need to add a basic locking mechanism:

Where you iterate:

```
private object _lockObject = new Object();

lock (_lockObject)
{
    foreach (var ctrl in cc)
    { ... }
}
```

Where you modify:

```
lock (_lockObject)
{
    cc.Add(someCtrl);
}
```

Comment: +1 for explanation in detail. Thank you. I'm using a DataTable with multi-threads. My simple question is, what if I lock when mdofiy from a thread, the lock of iteration from b thread will wait until modification is completed ? Is this such a easy thing like just to set 2 locks as your example ? And in my case, the _lockObject should be myDataTable ?

Comment: Too late answer, maybe it does not help you anymore but it might help others who came across. If `a` thread locks then `b` thread will block until `a` unlocks the object. If it never happens then `b` hangs forever if you don't take care of this situation. Yes, it's just that easy, 2 locks but is not the best solution. `_lockObject` can be your `myDataTable` or any other object.

Answer (score 0):

The error implies that your code is doing a `foreach` on a "collection/list" and inside the loop you are adding/deleting an item in the list.

The code you have shown does NOT do this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe somewhere in your code u are modifying a list inside a loop which iterates through the list. Just try to use a **for** loop instead of a foreach at this point.

Answer (score -1):

Instead, you might want to do it this way

```
void CheckChanges(Control.ControlCollection cc)
{
    try{
          for (int x = 0; x < cc.Count; x++)
          {
               Control ctrl = cc[x];
```

Comment: The "C# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute." error is a validation in "foreach" wherein the collection should not be modified during loop. "for" doesn't have this validation, care to share the -1?